# How can I convert from PCM to EVS audio file and decode back to PCM?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, converter, 3gp

everybody.
I have a problem with converting to 3GPP TS 26.442.

If I want to convert from .48k to .192 file, how am I supposed to get original audio file? Do I have to convert from any audio file (eg. MP3) to .48k (eg. PCM WAV) before I convert to .192 bitstream file of 3GPP?

Usage: EVS_cod.exe [Options] R Fs input_file bitstream_file

```
EVS_cod.exe 16400 48 audio.48k audionew.192
```

Comment: This is _very_ specific to EVS. Maybe this is more suited to an EVS support forum?

Comment: @Mark, I think it should, but I tried find EVS support forum, but no solutions founded. Any input supported audio format, before I convert to EVS? Otherwise, I decode back from EVS to PCM, it will be corrupted.